# gridview column width is not setting in asp.net in bound field

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, gridview

i need to set the max size of first column width but its not setting. while putting more data its expanding.

```
 <div style="width:640px">
 <table style="width:640px">
    <asp:GridView ID="gvChallan" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#cccccc" Width="646px" >
        <HeaderStyle Width="222px" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="itemsdescription" HeaderText="Items/ Description" HtmlEncode="false" HeaderStyle-Width="222px" />
       <asp:BoundField DataField="Quantity" HeaderText="QTY" ItemStyle-Width="10%" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="center" /> 
       <asp:BoundField DataField="TotalBoxes" HeaderText="Total Boxes" ItemStyle-Width="10%" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="center" /> 
            </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
     </table>
     </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `HeaderStyle-Width` instead of `ItemStyle-Width` as shown below. Also set full width of Grid itself

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="itemsdescription" HeaderText="Items/ Description" HtmlEncode="false" HeaderStyle-Width="222px"  />
```

Comment: `<HeaderStyle Width="222px" />` this can be also used.

Comment: On every column, you have to specify its own width. To do this in designer click on the smart tag > Edit Columns > Choose the column then in the property list go to HeaderStyle > Width and set it as 222px.

Answer (score 0):

First of all why do you have `<table style="width:640px">`? the `<asp:GridView>` will generate it's on table tag, you'll create warnings/issues with this.

You've defined the width you want it to take up with the div tag.  Therefore you don't need to specify the same value for the GridView. Set the GridView's width to 100%.  The set your first column to be 80%. So you'll have your column widths as 80%, 10% and 10%.

Answer (score 0):

You must define a **width for all your columns** so the values are respected; for example for a three columns grid try this in the **RowDataBound** event of your gridview:

```
protected void yourGrid_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
     e.Row.Cells[0].Style.Value =  "min-width:640px;";
     e.Row.Cells[1].Style.Value =  "min-width:200px;";
     e.Row.Cells[2].Style.Value =  "min-width:150px;";
}
```

Hope this helps someone.